# regex capturing groups in malformed text

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to apply a regex on some malformed text. The general format is:

`descriptor (one|two|three|four) code`

Ideal input example:

`hello world (one) 0039x`

And I want to capture 3 groups:

`"hello world", "one", "0039x"`

(notice the absent parenthesis in group(2))

Malformed examples:

```
hello (world) (two) 0039x
hello (world) three 0039x
hello world, four 0039x
hello (world)*,four 0039x
```

The `descriptor` should preserve any parenthesis and symbols (but commas are ignored), ie `"hello (world)*"` is also valid.

Here is what I came up with:

`([a-z0-9 \*\(\)]*),?\s?\(?(one|two|three|four)\)?\s([a-z0-9]+)`

It works okay, but the problem is the `descriptor` tends to greedily capture the open parenthesis. ie, from the ideal example:

`"hello world (", "one", "0039x"`

What's a better regex that will work with the normal case and also the malformed cases? Look-ahead is probably useful, but I'm not sure how to both use `(?:...)` and capture any parenthesis if it's also part of the `descriptor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to match until comma or whitespace just before `(one|two|three|four)` you can use this regex:

```
^(.+?)[\s,]\(?(one|two|three|four)\)?\s([a-z0-9]+)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dB1iD7/1)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only problem with your regexp is that you have the parentheses as optional, whereas your good/bad samples imply they are required (remove 2 `?`s):

```
([a-z0-9 \*\(\)]*),?\s?\((one|two|three|four)\)\s([a-z0-9]+)
```